# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. now what should i do?

Tags: python-3.x

I Have Code:

```
def nob(message):
    inp = message.text
    jum = len(inp)
    angka = random.randint(0,100)
    if jum < 8:
        client.reply_to(message, "please input the name!")
    else:
        client.reply_to(message, jum[inp:8] + " Is " + str(angka) + "% nob!")
```

and it's error like that:

```
client.reply_to(message, jum[inp:8] + " Is " + str(angka) + "% nob!")
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.
```

What Should I Do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is raised by the expression `jum[inp:8]`.  `jum` has been set to `len(inp)` which is an integer and integers are not subscriptable: an expression like `1[2]` does not have any sense.  Did'nt you mean `inp[inp:8]` instead? or just `inp` maybe?